# Find probability equation when there is two probabilities in the decision tree switching around

Tags: probability

The problem is like this:

---

The probability of success at 1st time is 0.625.

From the second time, if it is previously successful, the probability of success would become 0.83.

If it is previously unsuccessful, the probability of success would return to 0.625.

Is there a function, which could represent the probability of success at nth time?

---

In order words, after a success on any trial the probability of success on the next trial is 0.83 while after a failure it's 0.625, which is where it starts. I want the probability of success on the nth trial, considering all the ways to get there.

Appreciate Ethan Bolker for a better expression!

---

I totally got no idea about how to do this (I'm not a math major), but I need this equation in my research.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Please [edit] the question to clarify. I _think_ you are saying that after a success on any trial the probability of success on the next trial is $5/6$ while after a failure it's $5/8$, which is where it starts. You want the probability of success on the $n$th trial, considering all the ways to get there.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I will clarify. Sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Markov model. Let $P_s(n)$ be the probability of success at the $n$-th step and $P_f(n)$ the respective failure probability.

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
    P_s(n) \\
    P_f(n) \\
    \end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix}
    0.83 & 0.625 \\
    0.17 & 0.375 \\
    \end{matrix} \right]  \left[ \begin{matrix}
    P_s(n-1) \\
    P_f(n-1) \\
    \end{matrix} \right] 
$$

Let $M$ be that matrix in the middle:

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
    P_s(n) \\
    P_f(n) \\
    \end{matrix} \right] = M^n \left[ \begin{matrix}
    P_s(0) \\
    P_f(0) \\
    \end{matrix} \right] 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_n$ be the probability of success at the $n$-th step.

You have $p_1 = 0.625$.

Then you have the following relation :

$$p_{n+1}= 0.83 p_n + 0.625(1-p_n)$$

which can be rewritten as:

$$p_{n+1}= 0.205 p_n + 0.625$$

You can find the solution of such sequence relation by the following recipe :

- find the fixed point $x = 0.205 x + 0.625$
- Study the sequence $v_n = p_n-x$; you will find $(v_n)$ is a geometric sequence
- Express $v_n$ as a function of $n$
- Express $p_n$ as a function of $n$ using $p_n=v_n+x$

Answer (score 0):

You are facing standard Marcov chain with 2 states with transition probabilities $P($failure (state 1)$ \rightarrow $success (state 2)$ ) = 0.625, P(1 \rightarrow1 ) = 0.375, P(2 \rightarrow2 ) = 0.83, P(2 \rightarrow1 ) = 0.17$.

$a_{i,j}$ element of a matrix describing this chain is equivalent of transition between state $i$ to $j$.

The transition matrix $A$ is as follows:
\begin{bmatrix}
0.625 & 0.375 \\
0.83 & 0.17
\end{bmatrix}

$A^n$ describes transition between states in $n$ steps and element $a_{1,2}$ will describe your probability as you start from state $1$.